# Magento 2 - Same logged in, modal-authentication is showing

Tags: logging, magento2, checkout

Even though the customer is logged in, on click in "Proceed to checkout" modal-authentication is showed.

[image: Logged in but modal-authentication is showed]

I don't understand that is happening

This is my configurations in `Sales > Checkout`

[image: Configurations in Sales > Checkout]

Answer (score 0):

If you were changing settings for this, delete cookies in the browser. Happened some time ago when I've disabled this feature for the Porto theme.